# Ошибка в браузере с Vite и Ace code editor

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vite, ace

Ошибка:

```
Unable to infer path to ace from script src, use ace.config.set('basePath', 'path') to enable dynamic loading of modes and themes or with webpack use ace/webpack-resolver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
ace.config.set('basePath', '/node_modules/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict');
```